# DataSource No Longer Fills Data Calls VB 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using a DataSource in my form app, and it was working fine for calls made across the board, Fill, Add, Delete, etc...  It suddenly stopped working.  I get no errors on build, no data is added to any ComboBoxes, and no new Adds work either.

I created a new DataSource from the same database that works fine with the exact same connection.  The location of the database never moved, no changes were made to any properties of the DataSource or any of the Adapters assigned to the source, it just stopped working.  Here is some screen shots and code of my form.

I tried to do a Code Compare but since there are a bunch of Adapters assigned to the source I can't find any anomalies.  What would kill a data connection so that the code still sees the connection, but nothing gets filled?

The following code no longer works, no Fill or Add to DCGDataSet;

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DCGDataSet1.Main' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.MainTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DCGDataSet.Main)
    Me.MainTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DCGDataSet.Main)
    'comboClear()

End Sub

Private Sub btnAddNew_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

    ' Add new Job to the database
    Dim newJobRow As New DCGDataSetTableAdapters.MainTableAdapter
    Dim intInsert As Integer
    Dim jobText = txtBoxAddNewJob.Text
    intInsert = newJobRow.InsertJob(jobText)
    If intInsert = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("New Job Added")
        ' Update the comboBox values
        Me.MainTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DCGDataSet.Main)
        txtBoxAddNewJob.Text = ""
        clearTabOne()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Job Not Added")
    End If
End Sub
```

The following call for a ComboBox works fine, this is the new DataSource;

```
Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DCGDataSet1.Main' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.MainTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.DCGDataSet1.Main)

End Sub
```

These pics are of the two DS I am working with, the top one is the non-working DS.
[image: Non-Working DS]

[image: Working DS]

Entire .vb of Form1 Code;

```
Public Class MainForm

Dim strCurrency As String = ""
Dim acceptableKey As Boolean = False

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DCGDataSet1.Main' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.MainTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DCGDataSet.Main)
    Me.MainTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DCGDataSet.Main)
    comboClear()

End Sub

Private Sub btnAddNew_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

    ' Add new Job to the database
    Dim newJobRow As New DCGDataSetTableAdapters.MainTableAdapter
    Dim intInsert As Integer
    Dim jobText = txtBoxAddNewJob.Text
    intInsert = newJobRow.InsertJob(jobText)
    If intInsert = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("New Job Added")
        ' Update the comboBox values
        Me.MainTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DCGDataSet.Main)
        txtBoxAddNewJob.Text = ""
        clearTabOne()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Job Not Added")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TabPage2_Enter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Me.ActiveControl = txtBoxAddNewJob
    clearTabOne()
End Sub

Public Sub comboClear()
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
    ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1
End Sub

Private Sub TabPage1_Enter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    'comboClear()
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
    'ComboBox1.SelectedText = ""
End Sub

Private Sub TabPage3_Enter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    'comboClear()
    ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1
    clearTabOne()
End Sub

Private Sub btnDeleteJob_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim delJobID = ComboBox2.SelectedValue
    Dim delJobRowAdpt As New DCGDataSetTableAdapters.MainTableAdapter
    Dim delJobRow As DCGDataSet.MainRow
    Dim intDelete As Integer
    delJobRow = DCGDataSet.Main.FindByID(delJobID)
    delJobRow.Delete()
    intDelete = delJobRowAdpt.Update(DCGDataSet.Main)
    If intDelete = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Job Deleted")
        'comboClear()
        clearTabOne()
        'ComboBox2.SelectedValue = -1
        Me.MainTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DCGDataSet.Main)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Job Failed to Delete")
    End If
    ComboBox2.SelectedValue = -1
End Sub

Private Sub FillSubCombo(ByVal subJob As String)
    Dim selSubRow = DCGDataSet.SubBilling
    Dim selSubValue As New DCGDataSetTableAdapters.SubBillingTableAdapter
    Me.SubBillingTableAdapter.SubName(Me.DCGDataSet.SubBilling, subJob)

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim subJob As String = ComboBox1.Text
    If subJob.Length > 1 Then
        Label5.Visible = True
        ComboBox3.Visible = True
        FillSubCombo(subJob)
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub clearTabOne()
    Label5.Visible = False
    ComboBox3.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub TabPage4_Enter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    clearTabOne()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If (e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0 And e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9) OrElse (e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 And e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9) OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Then
        acceptableKey = True
    Else
        acceptableKey = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    ' Check for the flag being set in the KeyDown event.
    If acceptableKey = False Then
        ' Stop the character from being entered into the control since it is non-numerical.
        e.Handled = True
        Return
    Else
        If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back) Then
            If strCurrency.Length > 0 Then
                strCurrency = strCurrency.Substring(0, strCurrency.Length - 1)
            End If
        Else
            strCurrency = strCurrency & e.KeyChar
        End If

        If strCurrency.Length = 0 Then
            TextBox1.Text = ""
        ElseIf strCurrency.Length = 1 Then
            TextBox1.Text = "0.0" & strCurrency
        ElseIf strCurrency.Length = 2 Then
            TextBox1.Text = "0." & strCurrency
        ElseIf strCurrency.Length > 2 Then
            TextBox1.Text = strCurrency.Substring(0, strCurrency.Length - 2) & "." & strCurrency.Substring(strCurrency.Length - 2)
        End If
        TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.Text.Length, 0)

    End If
    e.Handled = True
End Sub

Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DCGDataSet1.Main' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.MainTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.DCGDataSet1.Main)

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Is it deliberate that you have no `Handles` clauses on `Form1_Load` and `btnAddNew_Click`?

Comment: "deliberate"?  No handles were created when the Form was created so I never noticed it.  It's interesting that the MainForm call created a handle...  That said, I never deleted any handles in Form or changed any of the default Subs.

Comment: Well, if you don't connect the event handler to the event, the event handler won't be run, so you would get the symptom you describe. Notice how the sample you give which works *does* have a `Handles` clause. I don't know why they disappeared from your code, but did you perhaps have a few `AddHandler` statements in a block of code which accidentally got deleted or commented out?

Comment: I added a Handles MyBase.Load to Form_Load and the code now works, just not sure why default code would either erase or never insert a Handle.  I do not have any AddHandler statements in my code, and I will edit the OP to show the full .vb code.

Comment: I've posted the solution we found as an answer for you; if you feel it warrants it, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not-working code is missing the `Handles` clauses on `Form1_Load` and `btnAddNew_Click`. If you don't connect the event handler to the event (using either a `Handles` clause or an `AddHandler` statement), the event handler won't be run.

Comment: I just noticed that, all my calls to Subs are missing Handles, I will make necessary edits.  Thanks for the solution!

Comment: @Mgfranz Looking into *why* this might have happened, apparently the Handles could fall off when saving a project in VS 2008: [VB 2008 Handles Clause disappears](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4e15c41e-035b-484a-ba64-27af0620ee60/vb-2008-handles-clause-disappears?forum=vbide) (I realise you're using VS 2010). Another reason would be if you had deleted controls and re-created them, and another is if you copy-and-pasted the code. Just in case you were wondering.

Comment: I think I know what caused the Handles to disappear.  I was playing with a custom control to create a Currency TextBox, when I found the control didn't work, I deleted the Class.  Apparently deleting the Class and all the associated code caused all my Handles to leave as well when I saved the project.  Lesson learned, I suppose I should try to reproduce the issue and post results.